# replicating amazon workplaces using ec2 in terms of security

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2, amazon-workspaces

Given Amazon workplaces is built on top of ec2, amazon workplaces is less flexible and more expensive vs ec2. How do they compare in terms of internet security? If Amazon workplaces is more secured, is there a way to DIY enhance ec2 instance so that the security level will get close to amazon workplaces? many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They both run Windows server, so the OS security is the same.

In WorkSpaces, there are two network connections -- one for the user to connect via the WorkSpaces client, and one connected to a VPC. Therefore, both EC2 and WorkSpaces can use Security Groups, NACLs and VPCs to manage security.

So, no real difference in terms of security unless you require connections to only come from a particular network/VPN connection.